# Getting values from an api call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, jsp

Hi all i have a url with returns values (https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=35.857368&lng=14.477653). I would like to get the values of sunset and sunrise. The code I am trying is the following but for some reason nothing is happening. Seems that I cannot access 'second level'

```
$.getJSON('https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=35.857368&lng=14.477653', function (data) {
var tr;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    tr = $('<tr/>');
    tr.append("<td>" + data[i].results[0].sunrise + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + data[i].sunset + "</td>");
    $('table').append(tr);
}});
```

Can someone please help me? thanks

Comment: @LGSon he's using `$.getJSON`, so it's an object already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither the response object nor `.results` is an array - remove the array indicies.

```js
const tr = $('tr');
$.getJSON('https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=35.857368&lng=14.477653', function (data) {
  console.log(data.results.sunrise + ' :: ' + data.results.sunset);
  tr.append("<td>" + data.results.sunrise + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td>" + data.results.sunset + "</td>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tr></tr></table>
```